# Executing SSIS packages via stored procedure? inside SSDB?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

Can we execute SSIS PACKAGE INSIDE SSDB via stored procedure?

My package does have ORACLE AND SQL data connections? can we pass them via parameters?

Anyways or suggestions?

Comment: Did you try any of these solutions?:    https://www.google.com/search?ei=a1c-W8CnD6To9APKuJ3QDQ&q=ssis+Login+failed+for+user+NT+AUTHORITY%5CANONYMOUS+LOGON&oq=ssis+Login+failed+for+user+NT+AUTHORITY%5CANONYMOUS+LOGON&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l3.5189.7202.0.7426.6.6.0.0.0.0.143.421.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.3.419...0j0i67k1j0i13k1.0.KZIADtmzXbs

Comment: When you run the package on the server, how did you do it?

Comment: What is the connection string that you are using for the server? For example, is Integrated Security = True? Have you read Microsoft's article on deploying and running SSIS packages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Integrated Security = SSPI. they both are equivalent right?

Comment: This is for sure a problem with authentication from one server to another. The SSIS server authenticates you and tries to pass that authentication to the database server which fails, probably because there is no "Active Directory Delegation" in place. Try to log on to the server using a Remote Desktop Connection and try to execute the package directly on the server. Does the problem persist? How is the package going to be run in production?

Comment: Can we execute SSIS package via stored procedure? with different connection managers?

Answer (score 1):

If your package is deployed to the catalog, then it can be executed by calling several SSISDB stored procedures.  From your connection manager, you can also parameterize options such as the connection string, server name, or initial catalog.  Right-click the connection manager, select Parameterize, choose the property, and match it to a new or existing parameter.  In the example below, the @execution_id parameter ties all of the configuration to this execution instance.  This SQL can be generated by clicking the Script button on the Execute Package window from the SSIS catalog.

```
--configure execution, if you're referencing an environment variable
-- @reference_id will tie this variable to your parameter otherwise it's null
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Your Package.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, 
@folder_name=N'Your Folder', @project_name=N'Your Project', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id

--set value for parameter below
DECLARE @var0 sql_variant = N'Connection String'
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=30, 
@parameter_name=N'ConnectionStringParameter', @parameter_value=@var0

--logging level, this is optional and will default to 1 (basic) if omitted
DECLARE @var1 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50,
 @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var1

--execute package
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id

GO
```